# Cannot compile gstreamer on Windows because it is missing glib-2.0

Tags: windows, rust, gstreamer, chocolatey, pkg-config

I'm trying to build a Rust program that implements gstreamer on Windows, but I can't figure out how to get the dependencies right. I keep getting this error:

```
--- stderr
`"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "glib-2.0" "glib-2.0 >= 2.42"` did not exit successfully: exit code: 1
--- stderr
Package glib-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glib-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'glib-2.0' found
Package glib-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glib-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'glib-2.0' found

Process finished with exit code 101
```

Here are my dependencies in `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
gstreamer = "0.16.1"
```

I installed pkg-config via chocolatey `pkgconfiglite`. I don't know how to get past this error and I'm stumped.

Comment: Have you installed `gstreamer-devel` (it is on Chocolatey too)?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: @Shepmaster . I added lines for my Cargo.toml--that's the only thing that causes the error.

Comment: @Jmb . Yes, I have `gstreamer-devel` installed via chocolatey. Still scratching my head about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\pkgconfig` to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` so that `pkg-config` can find the `.pc` file for GStreamer.

(Moved actual solution to asker's problem up here from comments. Original answer below the line so the comments make sense.)

---

According to [the gstreamer-rs README](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs#installation-windows):

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gstreamer mingw-w64-x86_64-gst-plugins-base \
      mingw-w64-x86_64-gst-plugins-good mingw-w64-x86_64-gst-plugins-bad \
      mingw-w64-x86_64-gst-plugins-ugly mingw-w64-x86_64-gst-libav \
      mingw-w64-x86_64-gst-rtsp-server
```

The README mentions issues with `pkg-config` and suggests `pkg-config-lite`, but you seem to already have that so it shouldn't be an issue.

The [Chocolatey `gstreamer-devel` package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/gstreamer-devel) *might* have similar results, but it's not the (apparently) official method.

Comment: I tried that but still no dice. Same errors as before. Although, I already do have `gstreamer-devel` installed as well. MSYS2 is supposed to bring up its own terminal, right? Thanks again for your help, by the way.

Comment: I think MSYS2 has its own terminal, but it's been a while since I've tried to work with it (or anything like this on Windows...) Maybe you need to `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="c:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\x86_64\\lib\\pkgconfig${PKG_CONFIG_PATH:+:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"`? That's mentioned as a thing that has to happen for the .msi-based installer

Comment: I tried using `pkg-config` like so:
`C:\Users\Zach\IdeaProjects\sentinel>pkg-config --variable=prefix glib-2.0`
`Package glib-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'glib-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'glib-2.0' found
`
I'm not exactly sure what the purpose of `pkg-config` is. Is its only purpose to return metainformation about installed libraries? If that's the case, it looks like it's not registering the msys installs.

Comment: `pkg-config` is used to retrieve things like linker flags to link a program to a particular library. Did you try running that `export` command and then seeing if `pkg-config` starts behaving?

Comment: Yes. I run that `export` command on MSYS2 MinGW and then `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and get  `c:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\pkgconfig:/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig`. Could you clarify what you mean by "behaving?" Sorry for the late reply (vacation) and thank you for your time!

Comment: If you installed via chocolatey, then that path is probably wrong. It should rather be something like `c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\gstreamer\lib\pkgconfig` (there should be a file named `gstreamer-1.0.pc` inside).

Comment: @jmb thanks for the comment. II went to `C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\lib\gstreamer` and only see the files `gstreamer.nupkg` and  `gstreamer.nuspec`. How would I get `gstreamer-1.0.pc` inside?

Comment: Try to search for that file on your computer, then add the path where you found it to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` (don't try to move it: `pkg-config` uses its location to find the other GStreamer devel files).

Comment: @Jmb I looked for that file and found that it was indeed installed at `C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\lib\pkgconfig`. For some reason, Windows wasn't picking it up so I had to set the environment variable myself to that path (surprisingly easy fix). Thanks again for your time!

Comment: I installed the official 2 packages, I got the same issue. It's `/c/gstreamer/1.0/msvc_x86_64/lib/pkgconfig/` nowadays, exporting PKG_CONFIG_PATH with that directory doesn't work for me :-(