# Where is the `glib-2.0` file on Linux?

Tags: linux, rust, gtk, pkg-config

I have a simple Gtk app in Rust, but I get this error when compiling:

```
Package glib-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glib-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'glib-2.0' found
```

And yes, I read [Cannot compile gstreamer on Windows because it is missing glib-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63026758/16775594), but it still doesn't contain all the information I need.

I put `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/` in `/home/user/.profile` (as shown in [Can't Set Environment Variables in ~/.profile](https://askubuntu.com/q/202193/1466830)), and I also ran it directly in the Rust project directory, to no avail. I used that path because it seemed closest to the one in the Windows question, though there were many `pkgconfig` directories on the system, in various places.

Here is my Rust code:

```rust
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow};

fn main() {
    let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id("org.example.HelloWorld")
        .build();

    app.connect_activate(|app| {
        // We create the main window.
        let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
            .application(app)
            .default_width(320)
            .default_height(200)
            .title("Hello, World!")
            .build();

        // Show the window.
        window.show();
    });

    app.run();
}
```

and here is Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "gtk_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
gtk = { version = "0.2", package = "gtk4" }
```

So my question: where is the `glib-2.0.pc` file on a Linux? Is it under a different name, or does it have to be installed?

Comment: Most likely you need to install it.

Comment: There's no reason for distros to include the `glib` development headers by default. You probably need to install it. It's `apt install libglib2.0-dev` on Debian+derivatives

Comment: @Smitop Thanks! I will try that as soon as I can, and I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Smitop: I tried your suggestion, but after installation I got this error when compiling my code: `Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.66' but version of GLib is 2.64.6`.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Your glib version is out of date, you need get a more recent version than your distro is providing. Installing glib from Debian unstable might work.

Comment: If you're developing for GTK in Rust, I'd highly recommend GNOME Builder and its Flatpak integration. You can use a runtime with newer dependencies without affecting the host.

Comment: @JamesWestman So judging by a brief search on SO, GNOME Builder enables application development in a sort of Gtk virtual environment, so that I don't need to install anything complicated on my computer?

Comment: Yes, if you add a flatpak manifest to your repository. See https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/getting-started.html.

Comment: @JamesWestman One more question: does `flatpak` replace or in any other way interfere with `cargo`, or can they be used in the same application?

Comment: You run your whole build system inside Flatpak, including Cargo or whatever other buildsystem. You'll need to include `"sdk-extensions": [ "org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.rust-stable" ]` in your manifest, then you should be able to use cargo as normal. [Here's an example of a Rust app's flatpak manifest](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/podcasts/-/blob/master/org.gnome.Podcasts.Devel.json).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue on Fedora 36 ARM. I've installed `libwebkitgtk`, `rust-gtk-sys-devel`, `libproxy-webkitgtk4`, `webkitgtk4`, `libsoup`, `libsoup-devel` and `webkitgtk4-devel` and it started working. Some of libraries above may not be needed for your issue. For fedora the command is:

```bash
sudo dnf install libwebkitgtk rust-gtk-sys-devel libproxy-webkitgtk4 webkitgtk4 libsoup libsoup-devel webkitgtk4-devel
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've since fixed the problem, I don't remember how now. I'll go ahead and accept this answer, though. By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend reading the [tour] for a general intro to how things work here.